# How to fix zoomed-in apps in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu

I am using Lubuntu and some apps are zoomed in so much that they are unusable, can anyone help me to fix it?

[image: Screenshot of VirtualBox]

Comment: Hold `CTRL` hit `0` (zero!)?   but in Virtualbox, Really?   I do not recognize the display; Tools in the left side panel, how did you get that? Version of VB? (click Help [menu?] then About ...)

Comment: @guiverc the image seems to show that the poster is using VirtualBox running **in** Lubuntu and not Lubuntu in VirtualBox. I'm saying this because of the panel at the bottom.